# Why is the GH4 considered Panasonic's flagship when the GX8 matches it in specs?

Tags: panasonic-lumix

Why is the Panasonic GH4 considered Panasonic's flagship Lumix camera? After the arrival of the GX8 it is matched spec for spec in virtually every category, the only true differences I noticed being that the GX8 now has sensor shift image stabilization (the GH4 doesn't) and lacks a headphone jack (the GH4 provides a headphone jack).

Comment: Honestly, I consider the GX8 the new flagship now. It's better or matches it in every way when it comes to photography.

Answer (score 3):

The GH4 still trumps the GX8 for serious video work - you've noted the lack of headphone socket on the GX8 which is definitely important, but the [DPReview preview](http://www.dpreview.com/articles/9485436827/the-big-beast-hands-on-with-the-panasonic-lumix-dmc-gx8?slide=6) notes a couple of potentially even bigger differences:

> Unlike the video-focused GH4, the GX8 doesn't offer 10-bit HDMI output and can't output video over HDMI at all while recording.

If what you're looking for is stills photography and some relatively simplistic video work, then it may well be that the GX8 is what you want - but if you want the higher level video features, which is where the GH4 is aimed, then it's still going to be the GH4 that you want. It's also worth noting that the GX8 isn't *that* much cheaper than the GH4 - in the UK at the moment, the GX8 is about £800 while the GH4 is £900.

Comment: The GH4 has more options for video formats, and higher bitrates - it can record at up to 200mbps. Also it can be switched between NTSC and PAL formats, the GX8 is locked to one or the other. And there is a battery grip available for the GH4.

Comment: @vclaw If you've got a reference for those, I'll add them into the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's not about the models. It's about the tiers. And the fact that no company updates all the tiers simultaneously, but has to stagger those releases so as a) not to kill their engineers and support staffs, and b) not to cannibalize the sales of one model for another.

The GH tier is the highest one Panasonic offers, and is always the first one out of the gate with the high-end features.  The GH4 came out with 4K video in the first quarter of 2014. The GX8 was a 2015 Q3 release--nearly two years later.  And the GH4 is probably going to be refreshed soon, since its main "headline" features have now trickled down to the lower tiers.  The key phrase you wrote is "after the arrival of the GX8"--but for the majority of the GH4's lifespan, the current GX model was the GX7, which doesn't compare as favorably to the GH4.

Lower models do get refreshed to look like closer matches for a relatively short period of time, so the tech/specs look like they're a better buy. But the overall picture of models and tiers is dynamic and constantly changing, since product releases tend to happen twice a year.  When a GH5 (or whatever they call it) comes out (possibly in Q1 2016), you're liable to see the specs of the two lines get farther apart again.